# Merging width and flex properties for utility classes

Tags: html, css, flexbox

On my site, I have a lot of utility classes that sets the width of elements. For almost all of the cases, the `width` property is perfect. The only issue is with flex box. For flex items, the `width` property does not set the width, and instead the `flex` property needs to be used. I tried combining the two into a single class like so:

```
.width-100 {
    width: 100px !important;
    flex: 0 0 100px !important;
}
```

Surprisingly enough, this worked on the few places I tried it. When an element is not using flexbox, its `width` gets set properly. When an element is using flexbox, the `flex` property makes sure it works as well. However, I am wondering if this is a good idea or not. Could there be possible bugs that I am simply not foreseeing right now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may fall into the case where you have `min-width` constraint and setting the `width` will make the flex item behave differently:

Here is a basic example:

```css
.container {
  display:flex;
  margin:5px;
}
.container > img {
  flex: 0 0 100px;
}

.container > span {
  flex-grow:1;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/100/200/100.jpg">
  <span></span>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/100/200/100.jpg" style="width:100px">
  <span></span>
</div>
```

In the first case the min-width constraint of the image will force it to have a width equal to `200px` whereas in the second case you will have `100px`. So it's wrong to assume that width isn't working in flexbox and you need `flex-basis`.Your code will indeed force the width to always be `100px` but it's not the same as `flex:0 0 100px` when dealing with flex items:

By the way, your code can be simplified to only

```
.width-100 {
    width: 100px !important;
    flex-shrink: 0 !important;
}
```

This should produce the same output because `flex-grow` is by default `0` and `flex-basis`  will consider the width you set.

Comment: Hmm I get what you mean. Thanks for the informative answer. However, the part about the code simplification does not seem to work.